# pytest how not to exit the for loop after first item assert fails

Tags: python, pytest, assert, assertion

I am new to python and pytest. I am trying to assert 2 lists of data. As the first data in the list is not matched, the assertion fails at that point and do not proceed for the next item. However I don't want my execution to stop , but complete the loop and capture the overall assertion results. Can someone help me how to achieve it?

**code**

```
def test_compare_database():
        records_src = [(1,James,smith,123),(2,Granpa,smith,124),(3,Linda,smith,123)]
        records_trg = [(1,James,smith,111),(2,Granpa,ron,124),(3,Linda,smith,123)]
        for a, b in zip(records_src, records_trg):
            assert a == b
```

**Output:The first item in the list comparison is failed which is correct. But it stops at that. I would want the whole for loop to run and capture the failed results.**

```
============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... collected 1 item

main_test.py::test_compare_database FAILED  
def test_compare_database():
            records_src = [(1,James,smith,123),(2,Granpa,smith,124),(3,Linda,smith,123)]
            records_trg = [(1,James,smith,111),(2,Granpa,ron,124),(3,Linda,smith,123)]
            for a, b in zip(records_src, records_trg):
>               assert a == b
E      AssertionError: assert (1,
 'James',
 'Smith',
 123,)
  != (1,
 'James',
 'Smith',
 111,)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use parametrized test to create multiple tests based on the data, so each pair of tuples will be asserted separately in a different test

```
def data_source():
    records_src = [(1, 'James', 'smith', 123), (2, 'Granpa', 'smith', 124), (3, 'Linda', 'smith', 123)]
    records_trg = [(1, 'James', 'smith', 111), (2, 'Granpa', 'ron', 124), (3, 'Linda', 'smith', 123)]
    for a, b in zip(records_src, records_trg):
        yield a, b


@pytest.mark.parametrize('a, b', data_source())
def test_compare_database(a, b):
    assert a == b
```

Console output:

```
main_test.py::test_compare_database[a0-b0] FAILED                     [ 33%]
Tests\main_test.py:33 (test_compare_database[a0-b0])
(1, 'James', 'smith', 123) != (1, 'James', 'smith', 111)

Expected :(1, 'James', 'smith', 111)
Actual   :(1, 'James', 'smith', 123)
<Click to see difference>

a = (1, 'James', 'smith', 123), b = (1, 'James', 'smith', 111)

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('a, b', data_source())
    def test_compare_database(a, b):
>       assert a == b
E       AssertionError: assert (1, 'James', 'smith', 123) == (1, 'James', 'smith', 111)

main_test.py:36: AssertionError
FAILED                     [ 66%]
Tests\main_test.py:33 (test_compare_database[a1-b1])
(2, 'Granpa', 'smith', 124) != (2, 'Granpa', 'ron', 124)

Expected :(2, 'Granpa', 'ron', 124)
Actual   :(2, 'Granpa', 'smith', 124)
<Click to see difference>

a = (2, 'Granpa', 'smith', 124), b = (2, 'Granpa', 'ron', 124)

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('a, b', data_source())
    def test_compare_database(a, b):
>       assert a == b
E       AssertionError: assert (2, 'Granpa', 'smith', 124) == (2, 'Granpa', 'ron', 124)

main_test.py:36: AssertionError
PASSED                     [100%]
```

Comment: Thanks you are a genius

Comment: Hi, This is giving me all the results in the loop .However I see a error as such "E           _pytest.outcomes.XFailed: [NOTRUN] yield tests were removed in pytest 4.0 - test_compare_database will be ignored"

Comment: @EverydayLearner update your pytest version.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "try" and "except" keywords in python allows for the errors to not interfere with the program. Was this what you were looking for? You can also change the "out" variable that I used into a list variable if that's what you want. I hope that this helps :)

```
James:int=1
smith:int=2
Granpa:int=3
Linda:int=4
ron:int=5

def test_compare_database()->str:
    out:str=''
    records_src = [(1,James,smith,123),(2,Granpa,smith,124),(3,Linda,smith,123)]
    records_trg = [(1,James,smith,111),(2,Granpa,ron,124),(3,Linda,smith,123)]

    for a, b in zip(records_src,records_trg):
        try:
            assert a==b
            out+="success between "+str(a)+" and "+str(b)+'!'
        except AssertionError as ae:
            out+="there was an assertion error in the program between "+str(a)+" and "+str(b)+'!'
        out+='\n'

    return out

print(test_compare_database())
```